# VS Code adds new line after < symbol on save

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I created a sample react native app. If I open the App.js file to edit the example code, the code gets changed if I save the file in visual studio code:

[image]

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Do you have Lint or Prettier installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The editor is formatting the content on save. You can either turn off the auto-formatting on save or figure out what formatter is causing the invalid output format.

To turn off formatting on save, go to preferences and search for `editor.formatOnSave` which you can then turn off.

If you want to fix the formatter, you'll have to look at the plugins installed and the formatter selected for the file type.

Comment: I'm having this problem with prettier. I set it to printWidth: 120, and still at 40 characters it goes to new line :(